# Hodge theory in higher eigen-spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, at.algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-analysis, sp.spectral-theory

Hodge theory for elliptic complexes $E$ identifies the space of harmonic sections with cohomology

$$\mathcal{H}(E) \simeq H(E).$$

A classical example with differential forms ($E = (\Omega,d)$) identifies the space of harmonic forms with de Rham cohomology. This shows that the operator $(\Delta -0)$ is able to recover topological information of the space.

**Question** How about other eigenspaces? Namely, can $(\Delta -\lambda)$ tell us anything interesting (preferably in the topological aspect)?

Comment: This wouldn't be invariant of the metric which would make it, at least naively, hard to recover topological information from it.

Comment: The space of harmonic forms $\mathcal{H}_g$ aren't invariant of the metric, but their dimensions are. Are the dimensions of $ker(\Delta - \lambda)$ at least invariant of metric?

Comment: I meant the dimension wouldn't be invariant. Consider the case of a torus, with the flat metric. Eigenspaces can be computed by Fourier decomposition.

Comment: As @WillSawin comments, the dimensions of eigenspaces of Laplace-Beltrami operators are not invariant under perturbations of metric. For example, the "square" torus has Laplacian eigenvalues essentially equal to sums of integer squares. The multiplicities are understandable via Gaussian integers. Slightly changing one of the lengths makes all the multiplicities $1$, instead (for incommensurate side lengths this follows from the obvious lazy proof.) :)

Comment: You may be interested in Bott, "Morse theory indomitable", which explains an idea of Witten's for how the eigenspaces of a deformed Laplacian, $\Delta_s$, can be related to Morse theory.

Comment: While the dimensions of individual eigenspaces depend on the choice of metric, one can cook up invariants like Ray-Singer torsion by considering all these dimensions at once. To get something truely topological, one needs to twist with an acyclic flat vector bundle.